# how to overwrite next_post_link

Tags: filters, next-post-link

Is there any custom php code that lets me overwrite `next_post_link` so I can customize it to my liking? I can add code in functions.php

Right now it shows next post
But I want to show something else

Comment: What would you like it to show?

Comment: Also, what's the context here? The function already has 2 arguments that allow you quite a bit of customisation at the moment of use, so a filter shouldn't be necessary. Are you working from a child theme?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/adjacent_post_link/

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily change only the URL of that link, because there is no filter that will allow you to do that, but...

[`next_post_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.2/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1992) uses `get_next_post_link`. There are no filters in any of these functions, but... [`get_next_post_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.2/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1976) uses `get_adjacent_post_link` and inside of that function you can see [`{$adjacent}_post_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.2/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2056) hook.

So now we can check [docs for that hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/adjacent_post_link/). And then write some code:

```
function my_next_post_link($output, $format, $link, $post, $adjacent) {
    return '<a href="<MY LINK">MY LINK LABEL</a>';
}
add_filter( 'next_post_link', 'my_next_post_link', 10, 5 );
```

PS. Most likely you also have to add some conditions in there, so you don't change every link on your site and only the one you want to.